# Screen capture of specific window on linux

Tags: python, linux, screenshot, video-recording

I am using a simulation (Mujoco) and its video recording capability is not working. So, a workaround would be to capture the simulation frame, make screenshots and assemble them to video.
However, I have not been able to find a window grabber that works on linux. SO far I have tried:
pygetwindow - is not supported for linux
python mss - is not able to grab a frame

Could you provide me with some alternatives? I would be very thankful

Answer (score -1):

This question is not what Stack Overflow is for - it's for fixing code. You provide the code, we try to fix it. But, anyway -

In our company we use OBS for recording video. It is free, and is advertised as working under Windows, MacOS and Linux - I can say that it works well under Windows.  https://obsproject.com/

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for answering regardless. I understand that I dont provide code explicitly. But I am not asking for video recording / editing advice. I am sorry if it came out like that. I need to be able to capture a screenshot of a specific window using python on linux. I have already ruled out pygetwindow and mss modules as they 1. are not compatible with linux and 2. dont provide window_handling functionality. I am asking for an alternative.
 OBS is a video recording and stream software and I have used it but it does not have an apk as far as I am concerned.